# How to make player stay on moving platform in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to create a program where the player has to jump on horizontally moving platforms to reach their high score. The player can move left and right and can jump.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

run = True
width = 500
height = 500
x = 250
y = 475
vel = 10
x_plat = 100
y_plat = 400
platform_vel = 5
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
isjump = False
jumpcount = 7.5
collision_tolerance = 10
gravity = 8

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


rect = Rect(x_plat, y_plat, 150, 20)

player = Rect(x, y, 25, 25)

while run:

    clock.tick(30)

    if rect.left >= 355 or rect.left < 1:
        platform_vel *= -1
    rect.left += platform_vel

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < (500 - 25):
        x += vel
    if not(isjump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True

    else:
        if jumpcount >= -7.5:
            y -= (jumpcount * abs(jumpcount)) * 1
            jumpcount -= 1
        else:
            jumpcount = 7.5
            isjump = False

    collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(rect, player)

    if collide:
        player.bottom = rect.top
        player.left += platform_vel
    rect.left += platform_vel


    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 0), rect)

    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 255, 255), player)


    pygame.display.update()

    surface.fill((255, 222, 173))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
```

If you run my code, when the player jumps onto the moving platform, the platform moves but the player doesn't move with it, making the player float in mid air.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help!

Answer (score 0):

The player didn't move at all with the code provided so I updated `x` and `y` references to `player.x` and `player.y`, then made some changes to implement gravity and collision checking with the platform and floor.

It's important to note that when on the platform, gravity still moves the player downward into the platform so they collide with the platform each clock tick and the "collide" logic runs.  It also allows the player to fall off the platform if moving left or right.

This seems to do what you want:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

run = True
width = 500
height = 500
vel = 10
x_plat = 100
y_plat = 400
platform_vel = 5
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
isjump = False
jumpcount = 7.5
collision_tolerance = 10
gravity = 1
player_vy = 0  # players vertical velocity

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
rect = Rect(x_plat, y_plat, 150, 20)
player = Rect(250, 475, 25, 25)

while run:

    clock.tick(30)

    if rect.left >= 355 or rect.left < 1:
        platform_vel *= -1

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.x > 0:
        player.x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.x < (500 - 25):
        player.x += vel
    if not(isjump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True        # suppress spacebar jumping until landing
            player_vy = -16      # give upward velocity
    player_vy += gravity         # accelerate downward due to gravity
    player.y += player_vy        # compute new height

    collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(rect, player)
    if collide and player_vy >= 0:   # falling and collide with platform?
        player.bottom = rect.top     # land on platform.
        player_vy = 0                # no longer falling
        player.left += platform_vel  # move with platform
        isjump = False               # enable jump

    if player.y > 475:  # don't fall off bottom of screen.
        player.y = 475  # land on bottom of screen
        player_vy = 0   # stop falling
        isjump = False  # allow jumping again

    rect.left += platform_vel  # move platform

    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 0), rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 255, 255), player)
    pygame.display.update()
    surface.fill((255, 222, 173))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
```